# trace involving an inverse matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Let

A: $n \times n$ symmetric positive definite matrix whose all elements satisfy $a_{ij}=O(m^2)$

B: $n \times n$ symmetric positive definite matrix whose all elements satisfy $b_{ij}=O(m)$

Then, is the following true?

$trace[A^{-1}B]=O(1/m)$ for $n=2,3,...$

When $n=1$, this seems to be correct.
But not sure when $n \ge 2$.
Are there any inequalities of trace that involves an inverse matrix as above?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is yes.  In particular, let $C = A^{-1}$.  Note that the entries of $C$ satisfy $c_{ij} = O(m^{-2})$.  We then have (by the symmetry of $A^{-1}$)
$$
\operatorname{trace}[A^{-1}B] = \sum_{i,j = 1}^n c_{ij}b_{ij} = 
\sum_{i,j = 1}^n O(m^{-2})O(m) = \sum_{i,j = 1}^n O(m^{-1}) = O(n^2/m)
$$

Comment: Thanks. But I don't understand why $c_{ij}=O(m^{-2})$ when $a_{ij}=O(m^2)$.

Comment: Cramer's tule for inverses, for example.